# Some UI buttons work and other don't on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am making an Android game and in my game I have probably around 20 UI buttons, maybe more. I have buttons that do in-app purchases and then just normal buttons. All of my buttons work except 3.

The 3 of them worked the other day but then just stopped and I am not sure what I changed. I have deleted the buttons and added them back in, that didn't work. I have duplicated a button that does work and tried using that and that doesn't work.

The weird thing is, when I do everything in Unity everything works, it is just when I export it to my phone through internal testing through Google Play. When I do that it is when those 3 buttons stop working.

I downloaded LDPlayer which is just an emulator for a phone. When I run my game on there two of the buttons work, the two that pull up the leaderboards and achievements, but the third doesn't. The third button has audio attached to it and plays when touched. The two button with a script attached to them call the code below when pressed. I am connected to Google Play Services and my account does log in when the game launches. I have to in app purchase buttons that work just fine so I know that it isn't me not being able to connect to the Google Services.

```
public void ShowLeaderboard()

{

Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();

Debug.Log("Pushed the leaderboard button.");

}
```

and

```
public void ShowAchievementUI()

{

Social.ShowAchievementsUI();

Debug.Log("pushed achievement button");

}
```

Like I said everything worked on an earlier version of my game, these functions haven't changed at all. My whole PlayGameServices Class hasn't changed at all since I created it and everything worked in the beginning.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. I have tried doing some Google searches and they said to go to the eventsystem and make sure that "force module active" was checked. I have made sure that script execution order was correct. I know the buttons are detecting my finger press because I have it change sprites on press and all three buttons are responding to the touch. I really don't know what else to do at this point. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Going to take a wild guess and say your Canvas is not scaling properly. When it scales go the screen size of your phone instead of Unity, some other UI element is blocking the click of the button. The easiest way to tell if this is the issue is if the buttons do not respond at all when tapping on them. If they do not change tint/color on the press and lift,  it is most likely another UI element eating the click.

Comment: I tried it on my phone and it is changing tint. So I know that the button is being recognized when I push it. I also made sure there weren't any other UI elements overlapping it by just putting it in an empty place by itself and still having the issue.

Comment: Interesting. It means the plugin calls are failing not the buttons. I would recommend getting [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=CjwKCAjwg4-EBhBwEiwAzYAlshyVDOKtQZagVeaiHSHqeEbLYn7BYTj0WjoiaA4CysaXfbKwJMUloBoCwJkQAvD_BwE) and use logcat to get error and warning messages from the device. You can also refine the logs to only be from Unity. When I'm on PC I can help you through this if you'd like. Doing this should tell you why these calls are failing.